# finish() not triggering onActivityResult

Tags: android

I want to refresh a list when the user goes back to the main Activity from a child Activity. I Overrode `onActivityResult` and the function is called when I press the back button on the child Activity. However, there are other ways to get back to the main Activity from the child Activity and all ways should trigger the refresh. However when I call `finish` from the child, `onActivityResult` is never called.

I use `startActivityForResult` to start the child activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(ConfGroupActivity.this, ConfGroupDetailsActivity.class);
ConfGroupActivity.this.startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

And I finish the child activity like this

```
setResult(0);
finish();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call setResult(0) that is actually the value for RESULT_CANCELLED. You need to call

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

Comment: Nice... I hadn't taken that into account.